# Слово, яким можна назвати когось, хто може опановувати нові технології?

Tags: одним-словом

Часто, коли людина пише резюме, то хотілось би знайти слово чи два, яке б замінило таку фразу:

> Здатний опанувати новітні технології

Наприклад, можна було б сказати:

> Богдан може опановувати нові технології, тому що він має велику базу
>   знань.

Отже, із замінником воно могло б звучати якось так:

> Богдан X, тому що він має велику базу знань.

Comment: а той Богдан - кмітливий :)

Comment: Будь ласка, уточніть ваше запитання. Бо людина не може бути "здатною опанувати, бо ерудована". Вона або може бути "здатною опанувати, бо здатна навчатися взагалі" (або простіше —  бо є розумною), або "**охочою** до новітній технологій", тобто жадібною до знань.

Comment: @Yola  я чому перепитав. В резюме зазвичай вказують саме "я люблю навчатися", а не "я здатний навчатися", бо останнє зрозуміло само собою (інакше подавач не зміг би вивчити технологію, з якою він зараз працює)

Comment: @Miroshko, ну, у англійців є *tech-savvy* - такий, що знається на новітніх технологіях, а цього не можна досягти без постійного навчання. Хоча, так, це не зовсім те. Також є *early adopter* - той хто використовує нові технології ще до їх широко прийняття.

Comment: @NashBridges, мається на увазі здатний у прийнятні терміни

Comment: @Yola не думаю, що тут можна обійтися одним словом. "Хутко сприймаю/засвоюю нові технології". Також є поняття напівжартівливе "вічний студент" (в лапках), якщо потрібно підкреслити, що ніколи не полишаєш навчання

Comment: @NashBridges, так, мабуть, щось типу швидко вчиться, то найліпше. До речі, ви можете оформити це як відповідь;)

Comment: savvy я б переклав як тямущий. "ТЯМУ́ЩИЙ, а, е. Здатний добре й швидко міркувати, осмислювати, розуміти що-небудь; кмітливий." tech-savvy значить технічно тямущий?

Comment: @Miroshko може *технічно підкований*, тут підкований у сенсі навчений/підготовлений.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не думаю, що тут можна обійтися одним словом:

> Швидко/хутко сприймаю/засвоюю нові технології

Також є напівжартівливе поняття "*вічний студент*" (в лапках). Його можна вживати паралельно, щоби підкреслити, що ніколи не полишаєш навчання і робиш це з любові до процесу, а не з примусу.

Answer (score 0):

Цього слова вочевидь ніде немає у словниках. Але воно мені спало на думку - новітній техноосвоювач. Можна звісно техноопановувач. Проте техноосвоювач - коротше і краще звучить.

Answer (score -2):

**дослідник інноваційних технологій**

або

**тестувальник інноваційних технологій**

Comment: -1: Наші критерії якості дещо відрізняються від того, що можна побачити на мовних форумах і блоґах. Необґрунтовані відповіді базуються лише на думці їхнього автора і тому викликають хвилю диспутів і заперечень. А якісні відповіді ґрунтуються на якісних джерелах: словниках, поважних сайтах тощо. Будь ласка, перегляньте сторінки [tour], [answer] а також [«Якими мають бути гарні відповіді»](http://meta.ukrainian.stackexchange.com/q/5/). Ви завжди можете виправити відповідь, зробивши її більш аргументованою. Для цього натисніть [edit].